# How can I set the time before the screen dims?

Tags: ios, settings, ipad

I've got an iPad 3 on iOS 5.1. When reading occasionally my screen will dim before I interact with the screen; it doesn't turn off and lock but it dims.

How can I lengthen the timer for this? Is it the same option as the "Auto Lock" timeout in the Settings app?

Answer (score 6):

It is determined by the Auto Lock time and cannot be set independently of it. The Auto Lock can be changed in Settings > General > Auto-Lock. The longer you set it to not auto-lock, the longer the display will maintain it's normal brightness.

Comment: Specifically it looks like it dims 15 seconds before the screen turns off entirely from my extremely limited testing.

Comment: At least under iOS 13.3, this is **Settings** > **Display & Brightness** > **Auto-Lock** (not **General**).

Comment: I too would like to adjust this. But it says, “When in low power mode, auto lock is reserved to 30 seconds”.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your piece of code in App Delegate after didFinishLaunching.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Comment: This is not Stack Overflow, nor is this question about code.

Answer (score -1):

http://bgr.com/2014/10/23/ios-8-1-features-tips-tricks-dimming/
Read this page and you can set it to dim manually with three home button pushes. This is a work around but you may actually like it since I did.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain to link-only answers. We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Links can change over time and then we lose the question-answer context. See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -